Issue with Destroy Function: Game Object Persistence Despite Implementation
everyone! I want to program a game. My problem is that my destroy function isn't working for both the player and the item. Everything else works fine (I made a flash item which doubles the speed). I get faster for 5 seconds, but the game object will not be destroyed.
game object:

player:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
    

    public float Speed;
    
    void timeout()
    {
        Speed = 20f;
    }

    void Update () {
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 move = transform.right * verticalInput;
        transform.Translate(move * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {    
            if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item"))
            {
                Speed = 40f;
                Destroy(flash);
                Invoke("timeout", 5);
            }
        
        }
}


I want the game object to be destroyed after collision, and the player to move faster for 5 seconds.

in general you might want to go away from Invoke ... what happens for instance if within the 5 seconds countdown you hit another flash item? .. => you would still only take the first one into account and reset the speed after the first 5 seconds.

Nowhere in your code there is anything called flash
=> are you sure you are destroying the right thing?
I suppose it should rather simply be
`Destroy(collision.gameObject);`


If the flash power-up is the one you're colliding to, then you can do this:
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item") && (collision.gameObject.name == "flash"))
{
    Speed = 40f;
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    Invoke("timeout", 5);
}

There are some other improvements that can be done on your code. Instead of hardcoding the timeout() function which you can rename at any point and then Invoke() will not work, you can do this:
Invoke(nameof(timeout), 5);

It is the same thing, the difference is, now you will get an error when compiling if you decide to rename the function without updating its name in the call to Invoke().
As alternatives to Invoke(), you can use CoRoutines or time stepping.

@Kilian No problem, but please read derHugo's comment as well. You need to think how to handle situations where the character has multiple power-ups or the same power-up twice. If you need help feel free to open a new question! Good luck with your game!
